# Comparing list values to the key values of a dictionary

Tags: python, list, dictionary

I have a list of codes

```
l = [1, 2, 3, 4]
```

And a dictionary of previously seen codes and their translation

```
d = {1: 'A', 2: 'B', 3: 'C' }
```

I am trying to compare the list values to the dict key and create a new dict with the dict values of the matches. I accomplished this with the code below:

```
x = {k: d[k] for k in l if k in d}
```

However I also want to keep the list values that don't appear in the existing dict because these it is important to track new values. I would like to store these in the new dict with the val being 'no match' or something. I am not sure how to do this in a pythonic way.

Final dict:

```
{1: 'A', 2: 'B', 3: 'C', 4: 'no match'}
```

I know that this can be done by creating a dataframe from the dictionary and a dataframe  from the list & outer joining but I would like to get better at dictionaries if possible!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use [`dict.get()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#dict.get), which can take a default value that is returned in case the key is not found in the dictionary:

```py
x = {k: d.get(k, 'no match') for k in l}
```